# The use of $0$ for the scalar $0$ as well as for the zero vector should cause no confusion, in general.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

I am reading the book "Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications" by Kreyszig and in one part the following comes out:

The use of $0$ for the scalar $0$ as well as for the zero vector should
cause no confusion, in general. If desirable for clarity, we can denote
the zero vector by $\theta$.

The reader may prove that for all vectors and scalars,

$(1a)$ $$0x = \theta$$

$(1b)$ $$\alpha \theta = \theta$$

and

$(2)$ $$(-1)x=-x.$$

I am trying to prove this: For $(1a)$, $0x=(0+0)x=0x+0x$ and so $0x=0x+0x$, with which $\theta=0x$.

For $(1b)$, $\alpha \theta=\alpha(\theta+\theta)=\alpha\theta+\alpha\theta$ and so $\alpha\theta=\alpha\theta+\alpha\theta$, with which $\theta=\alpha\theta$.

For $(2)$, as $(-1)x+x=(-1+1)x=0x=0$, it is concluded that $(-1)x=-x$.

Is this reasoning valid? Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks fine to me.